# javascript move buttons and resort into slice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to move items into a different div (so the user can select their favourite), however I need to the original list to always have a slice of 3, as it will be in a slider. So when an item is moved to the selected box the unselected box always keeps an li tag with 3 anchors wrapped in it

here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/8VrdE/308/

here  is my js

```
   var threelist = $("ul#nonSelected > a");
      for(var i = 0; i < threelist.length; i+=3) {
        threelist.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll("<li class='new'></li>");
      }

  function moveButton(elem) {
    if ($(elem).parent().parent().attr("id") == "nonSelected") {
      $(elem).detach().appendTo('#selected');

    } else {
      $(elem).detach().appendTo('#nonSelected');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changed function

```
function moveButton(elem) {
  if ($(elem).closest('ul').attr("id") == "nonSelected") {
    $(elem).detach().appendTo('#selected');

  } else {
    $(elem).detach().appendTo(
      // slice parent
      '#nonSelected '
      // slice
      + 'li'
      // dose not have 3 anchors
      + ':not(:has(a:eq(2)))'
      // select first slice(not have 3 a)
      + ':first'
      );
      // base selector
      // '#nonSelected li:not(:has(a:eq(2))):first'
  }
}
```